# Is there library function to determine which part of a string is number?

Tags: c#, string-parsing

Is there any library function to consume characters of a string and parse them as double - even if not the entire string is a number - and return the number of consumed characters *and* the parsed result?

I imagine something like `int ConsumeDouble(string text, out double value)`.Assume I have a `string s = "12.42;3.14"`, the function would read "12.42", stop at the semicolon, write 12.42 to value and return 5, because it consumed 5 characters.

I faintly remember that something like this existed in C but I can't find something like it in C#. Does such a function exist in the dot net framework? Or is there any way of achieving this without writing the a parser myself and without regex?

---

The above string `s` is just an example, in my use case there is no clear indication where I could expect numbers and where not.

---

If such a function does not exist, what would be the best way to write such a function? I thought about state machine to check which characters belong to a number, and then use `double.Parse()` to parse it.

Comment: I don't think there's a built in method for this, but it seems fairly easy to write one yourself. Remember that a string can be implicitly converted to a char array...

Comment: If there is really no function for this I probably need to write a small state machine to accomodate for all the possible number formats, like 3e-4 and such. But I'd like not to ^^

Comment: That's one way to do it, but probably not the best way... BTW, what if the string starts with a letter, like `string s = "z12.42;3.14"`, or has white spaces in it?

Comment: What would be the best way in your opinion @ZoharPeled?

Comment: How efficient does this have to be? And does the number always start at the beginning of the string, or might you have to skip some characters at the start to find the first digit (or + or -, presumably...)

Comment: the best way would be to leverage existing methods in the framework. I would probably use a couple of nested for loops with a `double.tryParse` inside. that is, if the number doesn't have to be in the beginning of the string. Worst case - O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming efficiency isn't too much of a concern, and also assuming that you always expect the number to begin at the START of the string and not partway through:

```
public static (double result, int consumed) ParseLongestNumber(string s)
{
    for (int n = s.Length; n > 0; --n)
    {
        string t = s.Substring(0, n);

        if (double.TryParse(t, out var r))
            return (r, n);
    }

    return (double.NaN, 0);
}
```

This should handle all the number formats, e.g. `ParseLongestNumber("-1.42e3;3.14")` will return `(-1420, 7)`.

If a number can't be parsed, it will return `(NaN, 0)`.

(Note: You didn't say you were using an old version of C# - if you are, you'll have to return the results via `out` parameters or via an explict `Tuple` rather than via the new-style tuples.)

A possible optimisation is to find the last possible numeric character and only parse up to that:

```
public static (double result, int consumed) ParseLongestNumber(string s)
{
    const string NUMBER_CHARS = "+-.,e0123456789";

    int n = 0;

    while (n < s.Length)
        if (NUMBER_CHARS.IndexOf(s[n]) < 0)
            break;
        else
            ++n;

    for (; n > 0; --n)
    {
        string t = s.Substring(0, n);

        if (double.TryParse(t, out var r))
            return (r, n);
    }

    return (double.NaN, 0);
}
```

Whether this optmisation is *actually* useful can only be determined by empirical testing.

Comment: That's about as efficient as it gets, I think. I don't imagine you can go under O(n) for such a task (but then again, I might be wrong). Of course, if the first number can start partway through the string, you'll need to add another loop... +1 for writing an answer similar to what I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, that you can return multiple values now. While this works well, I need to see, if I can improve the speed of it.

Comment: @churill You might be able to improve the speed by finding the last character that could possibly be part of a valid number and then starting the loop's `n` at that value rather than at `s.Length` - but I'm not sure that will really make much of a difference.

Comment: Or you can reverse the loop and store the previous parsed value in each iteration, returning it when the first `double.TryParse` fails. This might be a little more efficient for long strings, but unless you are parsing really long strings, and a very large amount of them in a tight loop, I seriously doubt there will be any noticeable efficiency difference.